# Extending settings.json in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to check a version of VSCode's settings.json into our team's git repo while still allowing for individual devs to add their own settings on top of that (i.e. in case they want to configure some extension they're using). Is it possible to tell VSCode to look at two different files? I.e. settings.json and settings-local.json, where settings-local.json is git-ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `code --user-data-dir /path/to/user/data/dir` to run vscode. VS Code will automatically generate some folders in the selected directory, and `settings.json` will be located in: `SELECTED_DIRECTORY/User/settings.json`.

Comment: How can I switch between the different user configurations? Running from desktop shortcut will launch VSCode with the default settings, but how to run it with the custom settings created the way you described in your answer?

Comment: @youssef You can edit the shortcut. What's your OS?

Comment: @youssef On xfce4: `xfce4-terminal -e 'code --user-data-dir /path/to/user/data/dir'`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Also found these links which gave me a bit more info now that I know what I'm searching for: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_advanced-cli-options and  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7243

Comment: This doesn't solve the question, because it doesn't explain how to combine several `settings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Local settings overrides (`settings.local.json`) · Issue #37519 · microsoft/vscode https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37519#issuecomment-344414444

This is a tip from a member of vscode developers.

Comment: The feature was dropped: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37519#issuecomment-344526825

Comment: not working (-1).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. As of Oct 16th, 2023, on a Mac, you can edit:
`~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`
a.k.a
`Users/myusername/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json` to achieve the desired functionality the OP needs.

I found this post because we have the same thing - our multi-contributor app, `our-app/settings.json` is version controlled and it was driving me bonkers not able to change workspace colors.
Apparently you can also find this in [image: Command menu with open user preferences JSON. This may be the way for Windows]