# Can I share VSCode settings without committing settings.json to my repository?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Several VSCode settings make sense for everyone on my team to have. However, VSCode automatically edits `settings.json` to add to the `file.associations` object. Those edits contribute to diff noise and unintentional sharing when `settings.json` is tracked. Is there another file I can commit to my repo to share settings that VSCode will not automatically edit?

[This seems to be the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526645/extending-settings-json-in-vscode), but the accepted answer seems cumbersome. I hope there is some 2nd file that VSCode will include and overlay over `settings.json` OR there is a way to put another key/value pair in `settings.json` that will force VSCode not to modify `settings.json` but instead modify a local settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentionally not supported due to obvious security issues. You need to install extensions that can do it for you, save/load and synch settings.

For example, the "Workspace Shared Settings" extension seems to do exactly what you need. There are many similar extensions.

I simply check in the complete settings.json into the repos. Other users can pick what they need. I keep it commented and well structured. Primitive manual solution but it works.

Comment: I complete this answer, adding that there has been an issue open since 2017 trying to improve setting.local.json with a lot of interactions on the vscode repository: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40233